# Updating python variable name using Sed in shell script

Tags: python, bash, sed

I have a py file where we need to update the value of a variable `table_name` from a shell script using `sed`. The value will be like `$ENV_NAME_ref_table` considering we have already exported ENV_NAME as `export ENV_NAME='staging'`.

What should be the sed command?

I have tried some with `sed -i` but can't figure out the regex.

`sed -i "s/table_name = ".*"/table_name = \"$ENV_NAME_reference\"/" /src/utils/abc.py`

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ - How can we fix what you did wrong without seeing it, and what it did, and what you expected/wanted it to do? Edit the question, show what you tried, input and output, and an example of what you hoped for. Good questions get good answers. :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Using `sed` to modify your Python script sounds like a supremely brittle and error-prone approach. What are you actually trying to accomplish? There is almost certainly a better way, using Python itself.

Comment: You need to delimit your shell variable. As it is `$ENV_NAME_reference` is taken to be the variable name and I believe you want "_reference" to be literal. Try `${ENV_NAME}_reference`. Also, why don't you do your refactoring in your editor where there should be syntax-sensitive features to help you with this? Or use conditionals (or a config file) within the code to control what environment you're running against (staging, etc.)?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ - better to make the pythin script configure itself accordingly, using appropriate values based on the environment provided at runtime, such as in and ENV var, or a CLI arg, or a config file, or whatever works for you. I do get that sometimes you can't edit the code...*but this is editing the code*, lol! Edit the code *once* so you can consistently test it, rather than every time in a way that can be affected adversely by unexpected conditions.

Comment: folks, I wouldn't even think of using sed to update that variable in .py file unless for a reason. The .py file in question does not get executed or interpreted locally, instead its part of a whole bunch of files that gets zipped and dumped in an ECR (Elastic Container Repository) in AWS. I need to set the table_name value correct before it gets zipped based on the env name. :)

Comment: I would still recommend separating the config from the code. One of those whole bunch of files could include a config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `sed` is extremely greedy when you use something like `.*` (although it seems to work in this case). I'd use this regular expression nevertheless:

```bash
$ ENV_NAME=staging 
$ sed -i.back -E "s/table_name[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\"[^\"]+\"/table_name = \"${ENV_NAME}_reference\"/" temp.py
$ tail temp.py.back temp.py
==> temp.py.back <==
table_name="foo"
table_name ="foo"
table_name= "foo"
table_name = "foo"
table_name  =  "foo"

==> temp.py <==
table_name = "staging_reference"
table_name = "staging_reference"
table_name = "staging_reference"
table_name = "staging_reference"
table_name = "staging_reference"
```

So, `table_name` followed by optional (`*`) whitespace (`[[:space:]]`), followed by `=`, followed by optional whitespace, followed by `"`, followed by many things that are not `"` (`[^"]+`), finally followed by `"`.

We need backslaces to escape the doubles quotes because we have to wrap the whole RE in double quotes to interpolate the `ENV_NAME` variable.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Much appreciated!
Just curious .. What is `i.back`?

Comment: What is `-i.back`?

Comment: @Codistan, it is just a tempfile `.back` but it is required for a BSD variant of sed, when using the `-i` flag.